# error al iniciar pycharm. configuracion de proyectos

Tags: django, intellij-idea

cuando abro pycharm siempre se abre en el ultimo proyecto en el que estuve trabajando, como puedo hacer que cuando lo abra se quede en la primera pantalla donde me pregunta si abrir uno de mis proyectos o crear uno nuevo

Comment: **Esto no es un error** "siempre se abre en el ultimo proyecto en el que estuve trabajando", simplemente deseas configurar de una forma diferente tu proyecto.

Answer (score -1):

¡Ya lo encontré! Está en `settings/system settings/` debajo de donde dice `startup/shutdown` desmarcar la casilla `reopen last project on startup`